# How To implement while(true){} in twig

Tags: twig

I would like to implement while(true) in twig. I wonder how to implement the below logic

```
while(true){
  /* Do something */
  if(/*some condition met */){
    break;
  }
}
```

in twig?

Comment: As Twig can iterate throught elements but not really do usual loops, this looks difficult. Interesting anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've not testet this, but something this way may produce an infinitive loop.

```
{% macro while() %}
    {% import _self as self %}
    {% if not /*some condition met */ %}
        {{ self.while() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```